# Visual studio 2019 fails to create rsync config when setting up remote connection

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, rsync, visual-studio-2019

So I an trying to add a remote connection to my Ubuntu 18.04 server for remote debugging in VS. Both when I add the connection and if I try to refresh remote headers I get the following error:

[image: An error has occured. Could not start the 'rsync' command on the remote host, please install it using your system package manager. Please see https://aka.ms/AA23jat for troubleshooting]

Checking the log I get the following more informative error:

```
liblinux.IO.RsyncException: Could not create daemon configuration file on remote device
```

How do I solve this exactly? Is there some way for me to set up this file manually if I can't get it to work automatically?

Here is the full error in the log if needed:

```
liblinux.IO.RsyncException: Could not start the 'rsync' command on the remote host, please install it using your system package manager. Please see https://aka.ms/AA23jat for troubleshooting. ---> liblinux.IO.RsyncException: Could not create daemon configuration file on remote device ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ShellStream'.
   at liblinux.Ssh.ShellStream.Write(String text)
   at liblinux.Ssh.ShellStream.WriteLine(String line)
   at liblinux.Shell.StreamingShell.WriteLine(String line)
   at liblinux.IO.RemoteRsyncDaemon.Start()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at liblinux.IO.RemoteRsyncDaemon.Start()
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.StartRemoteServer(RemoteRsyncDaemon daemon)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.StartRemoteServer(RemoteRsyncDaemon daemon)
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.PrepareForDirectorySync(Int32 sessionID, String localPath, String remotePath, RsyncDirection direction, RemoteRsyncDaemon daemon, RsyncVerbosity verbosity, Boolean recursive, List`1 includes, List`1 excludes, Boolean& sourcePathExists, String customOptions)
   at liblinux.IO.Rsync.<SyncDirectoryAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at liblinux.Services.RsyncRemoteCompilerIOImpl.<DownloadDirectoriesAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.<DownloadSysrootAsync>d__152.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.<CreateSysrootAsync>d__186.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at liblinux.Services.RemoteCompiler.<CreateLocalSysrootAsync>d__147.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Linux.Package.Dialogs.HeaderUpdateDialog.<DownloadUpdateAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
```